# How to format date from Sep 06, 2013 to 06-09-2013 in amchart (as in image)?

Tags: amcharts

How to format date from Sep 06, 2013 to 06-09-2013 in amchart when I hover on diagram ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using *categoryBalloonDateFormat* property:

"chartCursor": {"categoryBalloonDateFormat": "DD-MM-YYYY"}

Reference: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartCursor#categoryBalloonDateFormat